# html link "media" attribute (ie8)

Tags: internet-explorer, responsive-design, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, media-queries

This question is strictly related to IE8, I understand CSS3 `@media` queries.

Looking to switch a stylesheet based off the browser width, my code as is follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1000px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="large.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)">
```

(For simplicity/clarity - the stylesheets just change the color of a box)

Now the above code work fine in every browser, except of course IE8....

Doing some research to make sure it's not a compatibility issue, I found that IE8 does [support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534161(v=vs.85).aspx) the html `media` attribute....

**Question:** why isn't this working for POS IE8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer versions before IE9 do not support media queries.

If you are looking for a way of *degrading* the design for IE8 users, you may find IE's conditional commenting helpful. Using this, you can specify an IE 8/7/6 specific style sheet which over writes the previous rules.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style-ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

There is also a javascript plugin for media query support in browsers that don't natively support it:

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: Yea I know about them, I really think its odd that IE8 doesn't have anyway to detect device width...

Comment: not really odd, this stuff didn't exist back then. The above answer is going to be the best approach.

Comment: I mean when you have a "window" on Windows and it has the functionality or resizing "back then" you would think they would of created it, or at least add support, if the window didn't resize then it would be understandable to just detect of the device-type (print, handheld, etc) ...but, yea I'll accept his answer to close the question, thanks for your guys input and time I appreciate it!